# SQL: How do you return a record in a conditional statement and return a null value if false?

Tags: sql, null

I'm trying to return the records of the people who live in Bethany, Connecticut. If a person is also an employee, then their work center Id is also displayed. Otherwise, a null value is returned. I'm using the tables employee and person. What I'm stuck on is the CASE statement where I'm trying to return the work center id if a person is an employee (if they have an employee id), otherwise, a null value should print.

```
  SELECT last_name, 
         first_name, 
         birth_date, 
         city, 
         state, 
         employee_id, 
         work_center_id,
         (CASE 
               WHEN employee_id = 'IS NOT NULL' THEN work_center_id
               ELSE employee_id = 'NULL',
          END)
    FROM person, 
         employee
   WHERE city LIKE UPPER('Bethany') 
         AND state= 'Connecticut'
ORDER BY employee_id ASC;
```

I'm not sure how to get it to return a record if it satisfies a condition or print a null value when the condition does not exist. I've looked at the Oracle i-Learning slides and my teacher's slides and I haven't been able to find out how. I'm using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT last_name, 
       first_name, 
       birth_date, 
       city, 
       state, 
       employee_id, 
       work_center_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN employee_id IS NOT NULL THEN work_center_id 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS Work_CenterId 
FROM   person, 
       employee 
WHERE  city LIKE Upper('Bethany') 
       AND state = 'Connecticut' 
ORDER  BY employee_id ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks! It does run and display work center id for those who have an employee id. Will this make the employee id value null for a person that does not have an employee id? I'm just trying to make sure it does.